# Generalization of the relation between square numbers and odd numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, power-series, perfect-powers

We know that an easy way to obtain all the squares of the natural numbers is by adding starting from 1 all the natural odd numbers one at a time:

$1$ is itself a square

$1+3=4$

$1+3+5=9$

and so on...

I was wondering if this is just a specific case of a more generalized technique to obtain subsequentally and in order the terms of series of the form:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(x)^k}$, with $k$ being a non-zero natural number.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  The first differences of the sequence of squares are the odd numbers ($(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$).  Similarly you can get the first differences of the sequence of cubes, $(n+1)^3-n^3=3n^2+3n+1$ and so on.  Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean something like this:

[image]

I liked to make tables like this in high school. Each new line below the line of $x^k$ is made of cells which are the difference between the top cell and the top-left cell.

The important thing is that the constant we obtain at the bottom is:

$$k!=2 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot k$$

If you try to build a general relation from these tables, you obtain something like Newton's binomial:

$$(x+1)^k=\sum_{j=0}^k \left( \begin{array}( k \\ j \end{array} \right) x^j$$

Where:

$$\left( \begin{array}( k \\ j \end{array} \right)= \frac{k!}{j! (k-j)!}$$